# Updating iTunes Says It Will Change My Hard Drive

Tags: itunes, hard-drive

When trying to update my computers with itunes version 11.4, a message says it will change my personal computer's hard drive. What will it change?

Comment: It is probably just going to install new (iTunes) program files. Just in case, could you print a screenshot of the message?

Comment: Are you running OS X or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a application (like iTunes) or other try to modify your hard drive and install files on it, but your settings are such to prevent that.

It is advisable to set that alert so to prevent applications installing without your explicit approval.

The settings are in the system preferences - Security & Privacy - general tab.

Here you can set your choice what happens when a new Application tries to Install it self.

[image: install]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume here that you are running a Windows PC with Windows 7 or later, based on the wording in your question (a little clarification would go a long way :) ).

In the latest versions of Windows (from Vista onwards), Microsoft introduced '[User Account Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/user-account-control)', or UAC for short. This was to prevent malware and viruses from making unauthorised changes to your computer without your knowledge. Whenever you install an application or program on your computer, the screen will dim and a small window will pop up asking "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?" to verify that you want to authorise an application to be installed.

The iTunes installer pops up with this window because it needs to install specific program files in a restricted folder on your computer (`C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` on 64-bit machines) as well as some programs that will run in the background to monitor if you have plugged in an iPad, iPod or iPhone. It won't make any changes to any personal files or any other installed programs on your machine. It is perfectly safe to click okay on this window and allow iTunes to install, so long as you downloaded the iTunes installer directly from Apple, or are using Apple's Software Update program!

If you downloaded the installer from another source, I would recommend clicking 'Cancel' and getting another copy of iTunes from Apple directly at http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ (which will also provide you with the most up to date installer).